# Can I invent my own HTTP Status Code for when an entity is updated and the server returns a representation of the updated entity?

Tags: rest, http, api-design, http-status-codes

It drives me nuts that official [`HTTP Status Codes Spec`](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) *seems* to cover all the scenarios one might run into, but has really lame and wonky options for any type of `UPDATE/PATCH` request your system will need to handle.

**The (Lack of) Options**

> **200 OK**
>
> CLIENT: "Hey Server, what happened with that request I just
> sent you?"
>
> SERVER: "Nothing bad!"
>
> This is so vague it's dangerously useless. For the client, for the
> system, for logging, for analytics, for the entire internet. But this is the only option
> I've found for an `UPDATE` that actually returns a representation of
> the updated resource.
>
> **202 Accepted**
> CLIENT: "Hey Server, what happened with that request I
> just sent you?"
> SERVER: "I received it."
>
> Again, maybe a little more detail here? It's understandable that this
> could be used for long-running tasks as a thumbs-up to the client when
> they first submit the long-running task, but then once the
> long-running task is complete we're back to the default 200 OK. But
> again, useless for a 'standard' UPDATE (like updating your account
> bio, for example).
>
> **204 No Content**
>  CLIENT: "Hey Server, what's the status of that update request I just sent?"
>  SERVER: "I got that, and totally did
> the update. You should update the entity on your end too."
>  CLIENT:
> "Great! But you didn't send the entity through in your response."
> SERVER: "Of course not, I didn't need to. I left you a hint in the
> headers."
>  CLIENT: "Okay? So I can then look in the headers of your
> response and get the meta information I need to send *another* request
> to you to get the updated entity? Seems like you could have just sent
> me the updated entity."
>  SERVER: "I have nothing more to say on
> this matter."
>
> I mean, the Server had the updated entity *right there*. Why is it
> illegal to send it back as the body of the response? Again, useless
> for a simple UPDATE request.
>
> **205 Reset Content**
>  CLIENT: "Hey Server, what's the status on that UPDATE request I sent?"
>  SERVER: "I got that and I totally did
> the update. You should update it on your end too."
>  CLIENT:
> "Awesome! But you didn't send the updated entity back to me?"
> SERVER: "Of course not, that's illegal!"
>  CLIENT: "Really? Because
> it seems like you could easily just attach the updated entity to the
> body of your response and then I don't have to send *another* request
> just to get the updated entity."

And that's all of them. Not one of them is useful to fully describe the successful result of an account bio UPDATE **and** a returned updated entity.


**The Questions**

- So, can I just make up my own HTTP Status Code?
- 209 Entity Updated? [The numeric code seems to be available](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html).
- This is obviously not very "safe" to do with regard to how various clients (browsers,
  sdks, etc.) have baked-in rules for handling Status Codes.
- Any one else ever done this?
- I know Twitter returns their super-hip [`420 Enhance Your Calm`](https://httpstatusdogs.com/420-enhance-your-calm). We're all very impressed with their wit, and it doesn't seem to have broken the internet. But it's also a "rare" error code used for rate-limiting, not a typical success code.
- What are the gotchas that come along with colouring outside the lines of the official [HTTP Status Codes Spec](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html)?

> **Note Bene**
>
> I thought it would be obvious to all that [www.restapitutorial.com](https://restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) is *not*, in fact, the website of the
> standards body in charge of HTTP Status Codes, but rather just a handy
> website with a better UI than that of [www.iana.org](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) or
> [www.ietf.org](https://www.ietf.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xml).
>
> Apparently that was an erroneous assumption on my
> part. So in the spirit of science, if you're a fan of default blue, courier, and page-scrolls so
> long you need to pack a lunch then check out [www.iana.org](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml). Or, if you also have a fetish for broken image links, you can find the (probably) exact same information represented at
> [www.ietf.org](https://www.ietf.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xml).
>
> Otherwise, I've found [www.restapitutorial.com](https://restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) to be a very handy
> website with accurate information presented in a way that's just a nice little delight on an otherwise cold and snowy February day.

Comment: For whatever it's worth: I work in QA, and have been testing (REST) APIs for about 10 years now. I have yet to meet a front-end dev who gives a flippinF about HTTP status codes.

Comment: @SiKing Hahaha. Yup. I mean, the fact that there's more than five (1,2,3,4,5) is almost pointless. We're all dragging this vague, mostly useless, often confusing spec all over the internet for what reason now?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with a `200 OK` and returning the data in the body…?!

Comment: @deceze It's not specific enough for me. Given that when a resource is created `201` is the "correct" code, why such a general catch-all for any other operation?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the trusted list of status codes is the one from [IANA](https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml) (and not the one you used in your question).

Now, back to your question... Once [HTTP status codes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6) are extensible, you *could* create a new status code. But it doesn't mean you *should*.

---

Status code are meant to describe the result of the server's attempt to understand and satisfy the client's corresponding request. The [`200`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) status code defined in the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) and quoted below covers the scenario you described in your question. There's no need to define another status code that purpose.

> [**6.3.1.  200 OK**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231)
>
> The `200` (OK) status code indicates that the request has succeeded.
> The payload sent in a `200` response depends on the request method.
> For the methods defined by this specification, the intended meaning
> of the payload can be summarized as:
>
> - `GET`:  a representation of the target resource;
> - `HEAD`:  the same representation as `GET`, but without the representation data;
> - `POST`:  a representation of the status of, or results obtained from, the action;
> - `PUT`, `DELETE`: a representation of the status of the action;
> - `OPTIONS`:  a representation of the communications options;
> - `TRACE`:  a representation of the request message as received by the end server.

Now refer to the section of the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) that describes the semantics of the [`PUT`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4) method:

> If the target resource does not have a current representation and the
> `PUT` successfully creates one, then the origin server MUST inform the
> user agent by sending a `201` (Created) response.  If the target
> resource does have a current representation and that representation
> is successfully modified in accordance with the state of the enclosed
> representation, then the origin server MUST send either a `200` (OK) or
> a `204` (No Content) response to indicate successful completion of the
> request.

In a similar way, [`200`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1) is also suitable as result of [`PATCH`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2) requests that return a representation for the resource that has been patched.

If client doesn't require a representation of the resource that has been modified, return [`204`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5).

---

For an *optimal solution*, you may want allow the client to decide whether a representation is required or not. For this purpose, you can use the [`Prefer`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7240#section-2) header defined in the [RFC 7240](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7240) with the [`return`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7240#section-4.2) preference, where the value can be either `representation` or `minimal`:

> [**4.2.  The "return=representation" and "return=minimal" Preferences**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7240#section-4.2)
>
> The `return=representation` preference indicates that the client prefers that the server include an entity representing the current state of the resource in the response to a successful request.
>
> The `return=minimal` preference, on the other hand, indicates that the client wishes the server to return only a minimal response to a successful request.  Typically, such responses would utilize the `204` (No Content) status, but other codes MAY be used as appropriate, such as a `200` (OK) status with a zero-length response entity.  The determination of what constitutes an appropriate minimal response is solely at the discretion of the server.

---

<sup>**Side note:** New status codes should follow the [requirements](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-8.2.2) described in the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231).</sup>

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to lay this out in such great detail. You've made an excellent argument within the confines of the current spec. I just don't agree with the current spec. The fact that a `201` exists is argument enough for (at least) a "`209 Updated`" in the same manner as a `201 Created`. And the fact that the spec is so patchy leads me to conclude that it's mostly useless. Which is why I suspect that the vast majority of programmers only use 10% of it.

Answer (score -1):

You probably need some reframing here. HTTP status codes do not express *business logic responses*, they are from the perspective of the *HTTP protocol*. `200 OK` means the server has carried out the request you gave it as requested. That is purposefully broad, since the request could be one of a practically infinite number of business logic requests. There can’t possibly be a unique code for every possible kind of request or action a server took, since that is unique to each application.

If you have requested the server to update some data with a `PUT` request, then `200 OK` means “I have successfully updated that data, as requested”. There’s no particular need to differentiate that with a more specific code. Presumably you know what you requested of the server, and `200 OK` means that request was fulfilled.

The more specific `2xx` codes that do exist express something unique *from the perspective of HTTP*. `201 Created` means a new resource with a new URI is now available, and that URI has been returned in the `Location` header. `202 Accepted` means the server will (probably) fulfill your request, but hasn’t done so yet so there’s no new resource for you to see at this moment and/or the changes aren’t reflected to the current resource yet. `204 No Content` means the server fulfilled your request, but the response does not contain any body data and hence the client does not need to/should not try to process the response body in any way.

All these responses mean the same thing: **your request has been successfully acted upon.** They only express slightly different nuances in the *response* to that request, which has nothing to do with the *action the request expressed*. All these response codes are equally valid for any sort of operation, be it update, create, delete, or any other sort of operation.

To hammer this home, the server *might* respond to a `DELETE /user/42` request with `201 Created`; this would make sense if the deletion may take a while to actually carry out, and there’s a new URI for you now where you can check on the status of that operation. `201 Created` does not mean “a new user was created”, it means “the request was accepted (because it’s in the `2xx` range), and there’s a new *HTTP resource* in relation to this request which you may want to check out.”

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write such an excellent answer. You *have* framed the problem very well. And you're not wrong. I totally "get it". I just think the spec is wrong. Your `DELETE` example sums it up very nicely. I understand that a `DELETE` request can *technically* receive a legal response from the server in the form of `201 Created`, I just think that's logically absurd.

Comment: Well, that's *your* problem.  `201 Created` as a response for `DELETE` *is*… funny, but only if you interpret it wrong. An affirmative response (`2xx`) is already affirmative, that's all you need. It's about *request-response*. The server is *at your service*. You *request* something of it, it carries out the request. It doesn't need to be anything more than *affirmative.*